# "...the pleasure enjoyed" – placement of adjective?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

> A person should not think that happiness is the total pleasure *enjoyed*.

In this sentence, "enjoyed" comes after the subject it describes, even though it is not a phrase or clause. I thought only the phrase or clause could come after the 
subject it describes or modifies, or at least that is what the websites I visited say. Why isn't it "enjoyed pleasure"and sounds so natural?

Comment: It's the remains of a deceased relative clause: _the total pleasure (which is) enjoyed (by `Indef`)_. The parenthesized materials get deleted by _whiz_-deletion and Indefinite Passive Agent deletion, leaving only _enjoyed_ behind.

Comment: John Lawler is a greater authority on deceased relatives than Columbo.

Comment: I think your use of the term subject is not correct. "pleasure" is no subject.

Comment: It sounds weird, because it's redundant.  Pleasure isn't _enjoyed_, it's _experienced_ or _had_.  As for the positioning, John Lawler is of course correct about how it came about. This is an example of a  _postnominal modifier_; not at all  uncommon in English. "The items received were not worth the money spent."

Answer (score -1):

"Enjoyed" is an adjective (pp). Adjectives are used attributively (good boy), predicatively (The boy is good) and postpositively after noun or pronoun(pleasure enjoyed).

This postpositve use is not that common as are the other two. It is mostly used in certain fixed expressions (devil incarnate), after pronoun(nothing special), to change meaning (responsible men<> men responsible),after superlative attributive adjective (the nearest shop available) and after the noun as a part of reduced relative clause(pleasure enjoyed).

In the above example "enjoyed" can be used attributively. But "enjoyed" gains in intensity and force and establishes a direct relationship with "happiness", which the attributive use couldn't lend.

Comment: May I be favoured with the reason why it is down voted.